# QGIS attributes table shows wrong data when printing Timestamp with Milliseconds

Tags: qgis, geojson, datetime

I'm using QGIS to Debug Geometries and corresponding times. For that, I created GeoJSON in C# and added 3 timestamps as attributes:

```
feature.Properties.Add("CreatedUTC", CreatedUTC.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
feature.Properties.Add("StartUTC", StartUTC.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
feature.Properties.Add("EndUTC", EndUTC.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
```

The result looked like that:

[image]

As I was looking for an error related to MilliSeconds, I was confused to see only 0-millisecond-entries. So I added some leading text:

```
feature.Properties.Add("CreatedUTC", "d "+CreatedUTC.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
feature.Properties.Add("StartUTC", "d " + StartUTC.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
feature.Properties.Add("EndUTC", "d " + EndUTC.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Result:

[image]

QGis-Version: 3.18.1

What am I doing wrong; is there some attributes interpreter that might misinterpret my data?

Here's some extract from both GeoJSONs:

1.) Just Timestamp

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [...]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "CreatedUTC": "11:48:26.060",
            "StartUTC": "11:48:18.060",
            "EndUTC": "11:48:26.060"
        }
    }
  }
```

2.) With a `d`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [... ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "CreatedUTC": "d 11:48:26.060",
            "StartUTC": "d 11:48:18.060",
            "EndUTC": "d 11:48:26.060"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In the first case, QGIS adds the values as `QTime` objects and convert milliseconds to zeros. I don't know why.
- In the second case (`d` case), QGIS adds the values as string. Everything is as it should be.

One of the solution:

- Open `Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer`
- Select the file.
- Set `DATE_AS_STRING` to `Yes`.

  [image]

Result:

[image]